# Telegram bots not working After this error:Account Suspended

Tags: bots, telegram, telegram-bot, php-telegram-bot

[image]

Hello

My hosting account was blocked, but reopened after 6 hours,

But my robots didn't work anymore,

I tried the `setwebhook` again, but it didn't work.

What should I do?

Comment: _"didn't work"_ - that's a little vague. what error are you getting or is it silent failure? Does the endpoint you've created respond now (when you trigger it through browser/postman)?

Answer (score 0):

Write to [Telegram @botsupport](https://telegram.me/botsupport) or try to regenerate API token and set webhook again.